# How to set a CSS ID attribute to a Symfony2 form input

Tags: html, symfony, formbuilder

This question is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734821/how-to-set-a-class-attribute-to-a-symfony2-form-input). There [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734821/how-to-set-a-class-attribute-to-a-symfony2-form-input#answer-13358945) for setting the CSS class was to add it into the 3rd parameter of a call to FormBuilder::add():

```
->add('title', null, array('attr' => array('class'=>'span2')))
```

Unfortunately, this does not work for setting the CSS id. When I do

```
->add('title', null, array('attr' => array('id'=>'title-field')))
```

... this is ignored. The ID remains something like namespace_formtype_field.

How can I set the CSS ID, if at all?

Comment: Do you really want to change default auto-generated ID?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I have a web application that I want to port to Symfony, but I need to keep the Javascript and functional tests working. Some of them rely on CSS IDs.

Comment: try with twig {{ form_widget(form, { 'attr': {'id': 'title-field'} }) }}

Comment: Nissan, this will probably work and I will go this route if nothing else helps (I want to keep my tests working on either implementation), but I was hoping to keep rendering the whole form with a single {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}.

Comment: Have you looked into form theming? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming I think that you could overwrite the base field type to include your custom ID attribute.

Comment: Michi, thank you very much, I was totally not aware of this possibility.

Comment: Using `attr : { id: title-field })` either using FormBuilder or Twig view will result in 2 id attributes on the input element (Symfony and custom).

Comment: I believe that the symfony way is to do this in twig as its considered a part of the display logic, and its discouraged to do this on the form type itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am convinced now there is no easy answer. The closest seems to in fact change the markup by using [form theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming). Thank you [Michi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384273/michi) for pointing this way.

Answer (score 25):

You can do it when you render your field in twig, if you set your id outside of the 'attributes' array like so:

```
{{ form_widget(form.field, { 'id': 'my_custom_id',  'attr': { 'class' : 'my_custom_class }} )}}
```

Comment: The current "right" answer is wrong. In your Twig you can alter the id's as you have stated, this is EXTREMELY useful and applicable, however be careful to make your id's unique or you will get very unpredictable JS

Comment: thank you : {{ form_widget(form.address, {'id': 'autoComplete', 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','type': 'search'}}) }}  it works for me

Answer (score 10):

At twig level, you can simply do this:

`{{ form_widget(form. title, { 'id': 'title-field' }) }}`

Tested on Symfony 2.3.4

Answer (score 4):

Since an HTML element cannot have multiple ID's, what you're trying to accomplish isn't possible because Symfony already uses ID's on form elements.

The way to solve this would be to change your JavaScript to use classes instead and using

```
->add('title', null, array(
    'attr' => array(
        'class'=>'title-field'
    )
))
```

The other way is to change the ID's your JavaScript uses to the Symfony ones.

Comment: Pier-Luc, thank you, but either of your suggestions means that I have two versions of my tests and Javascript, one for Symfony, one for the other implementation. I'd rather avoid this.