# Symfony2 form id and name attributes are duplicated

Tags: symfony, twig

i am trying to use the symfony form builder to make a form which has 3 fields, name, country and language - i want the form elements to have an id and a name but it creates 2 each time

in the LanguageType

```
        'id' => 'country_code2',
        'name' => 'country_code'
```

in twig:

```
{{ form_widget(form.country_code, {'id': 'country_Code', 'name': 'country_Code'}) }}
```

is there a way to stop the symfony generated auto id/name

is there any documentation about this 'feature'?

Comment: Can you post the lines where you create the form? The code you published is kind on confusing. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070763/how-to-set-a-css-id-attribute-to-a-symfony2-form-input

Comment: i the end i decided to stick with the id and name that symfony is sticking in for me. why fight the power!!

Comment: please post your full type.

Also, to override in twig:

{{ form_widget(form.country_code, {'attr' : {'id': 'country_Code', 'name': 'country_Code'}}) }}

Apart from that, have a look at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.1/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig

Comment: To override the id you need to move it outside the `attr` property, like so: `{{ form_widget(form.country_code, {'id': 'country_Code', 'attr' : { ... }}) }}`