# how to style a symfony2 form button

Tags: html, css, forms, symfony

How do I simply add a css class or inline style to a button like this? Is there something you can put in that array() where I got label?

```
private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('video_delete', array('id' => $id)))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Radera denna video'))
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

I tried the aged old trick of looking at the elements id to see if I could sort of hack it by putting #ItsId in my css file, but no it doesn't have an id. It renders like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/site/web/app_dev.php/Media/video/1/delete">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">

        <div id="form">
            <div>
                <button type="submit" id="form_submit" name="form[submit]">
                    Radera denna video
                </button>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="2c2889b6744aade419618485e1b3ce0c9c341a42">

        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a class attribute to a Symfony2 form input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734821/how-to-set-a-class-attribute-to-a-symfony2-form-input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
->add('submit', 'submit', array(
    'label' => 'Radera denna video', 
    'attr' => array('class' => 'class-you-wish-to-add')
));
```

This is a duplicate of:
[How to set a class attribute to a Symfony2 form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734821/how-to-set-a-class-attribute-to-a-symfony2-form-input)

Answer (score 2):

```
'attr'=> array('class'=>'span2')
```

TRy this for add an attribut ;)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can put styles into the array using

```
->add('submit', 'submit', array(
    'label' => 'Radera denna video',
    'attr'  => array(
        'class' => 'your-class',
    ),
)
```

This, in my opinion, is the wrong place to put your styling details.

In my opinion, function should be in the `Type` (so if you had a bundle based javascript that used a set class then it should be set in this class) but styles should be based in the templates

```
{{ form_widget(form.submit, {'attr': {'class': 'your-class'}}) }}
```

This allows for your forms to be placed in other templates without being tied to a specific styling.