# How to add a custom class to select tag in Symfony2 FormType

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, twig

I need to add a custom class to my select tag (`<select>`) generated by an `FormType` with symfony2. 
All options are generated by Symfony

```
$builder->add(
    'birthday',
    null,
    array(
        'label' => 'form.birthday'
       , 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'
    )
)
```

and the generate code is:

```
<div id="fos_user_registration_form_birthday" placeholder="Mot de passe" class="form-control">
  <select id="fos_user_registration_form_birthday_day" name="fos_user_registration_form[birthday][day]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    ...
  </select>
  <select id="fos_user_registration_form_birthday_month" name="fos_user_registration_form[birthday][month]">
    <option value="1">jan</option>
    ...
  </select>
  <select id="fos_user_registration_form_birthday_year"    name="fos_user_registration_form[birthday][year]">
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    ...
  </select>
</div>
```

And, I need to add a custom class to this:

```
<select id="fos_user_registration_form_birthday_day" name="fos_user_registration_form[birthday][day]">
```

I've tried this solution in my html content:

```
{{ form_widget(form.birthday, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'form.password'|trans, 'class': 'test'}}) }}
```

But the `test` class is added to my div (`<div id="fos_user_registration_form_birthday" placeholder="Mot de passe" class="form-control"></div>`), not to my `select` tag.

Any suggestions?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734821/how-to-set-a-class-attribute-to-a-symfony2-form-input

Answer (score 1):

In your Form class, you can set the class using the attr option.
You can already do it inside your Form Type, or later in your template, like you just did.

It PROBABLY does not use your 'test' class, because the birthday widget does not use it. Please search your whole project for "birthday_widget" and see if it uses a hardcoded form-control class. If it does, you can write an if statement checking if attr.class is definer or add something like this:

```
{% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}
```

Edit: Can you also try rendering each day,month and year separately (I'm not sure if that will work, because I do not know the birthday type), like so...

```
form_widget(form.birthday.day, {'attr': {'class': 'test'}})
```

Another thing you can try is to edit your Form Type.

Try to add this after you add method:

```
$builder->get('birthday')->get('day')->setAttribute('class', 'test'); // Also try with ->get('days')
```

I'm almost sure something above will work.