# Add a specific CSS-class to Symfony2 form

Tags: symfony

I haven't found a solution for the problem yet. I assume that I can do it through Twig, but I don't know how. I'll be thankful for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a class attribute to a Symfony2 form input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734821/how-to-set-a-class-attribute-to-a-symfony2-form-input)

Comment: I haven't meant a form field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render a widget, you can add class with name foo, like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
```

If you want to add class foo to form element (tag), then you can use the same syntax:

```
{{ form(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo'} }) }}
```

Check out [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-widget-view-variables).