# Symfony2 - add attribute/class to single select option

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

Having form `select` field like:

```
$builder->add('foo', new ChoiceType, $this->defaults + [
                'choices'           => [/* some choices as key->value*/],
            ]);
```

I would like to add class to some of the options, so it renders like:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">foo</option>
    <option value="2">bar</option>
    <option value="3" class="showModal">baz</option>
</select>
```

How to achieve it? Important thing is that I would like to do this inside form type, not in template.

Similar problem has been described: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734821/how-to-set-a-class-attribute-to-a-symfony2-form-input), but it was about `input` field.

Comment: its not possible, but this will help you https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3836

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on this post..
You can use the `choice_attr` option, like this :

```
        $builder
            ->add('cours', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $this->getCours(),
                'required' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'select2'
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
                'choice_attr' => function($choice, $key, $value) {
                    return ['class' => 'my_class'];
                },
            ])
        ;
```