# Apply class to Symfony2 Form Label and Div

Tags: php, symfony

I'm attempting to set the class on a class on a form label using form builder.

Here's my code:

```
->add('email','text',array(
                    'label_attr' => array(
                        'class' =>  'CUSTOM_LABEL_CLASS'
                    ),
                ))
```

But here's my output:

```
<label class="CUSTOM_LABEL_CLASS required">Due Date</label>
```

how to delete the required prefix ?? thanks ,

*** other ptoblem ***

```
<div>
<label class="CUSTOM_LABEL_CLASS required" for="email">Due Date</label><input name="email" id="email" required="required" type="text">
</div>
```

how to set a class and id to the **div** tag ?

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734821/how-to-set-a-class-attribute-to-a-symfony2-form-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields are `required` by default. You have to specify `'required' => false` to avoid it.

```
->add('email','text',array(
      'required' => false,
      'label_attr' => array(
          'class' =>  'CUSTOM_LABEL_CLASS'
       ),
))
```

About your second question, the simplest way would be to add code in the template :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <div class="myClass">
        {{ form_widget(email) }}
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Or create a new specific form block, or also modify existing one : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming

Comment: thanks , the solution of 'required'  => 'false'  , work for me :) but showing of  the div doesn't : it show me :
<div class="myClass">
<div>
<input name="email" id="email" required="required" type="text">
</div>
</div>

thanks again ,

Comment: Great, last step : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: yeah , but can you give me  solution for the div class ?

Comment: @hz4web You need to use the workaround explained in the answer or create a new twig block template : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming