# How include an attribute 'class' rendering a form

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a contact form and I'm trying to put a class to an input of my form.

This is in the ContactType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Contact::class,
    ]);
}
```

And this in my twig:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.name, {attr: {class: 'myclass', placeholder: 'name'} }) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I get this html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_name" name="contact[name]" required="required" placeholder="name">
```

It's working for placeholder, but not to class. I have tried to put the attr in the builder and it is the same. Is the class `form-control` overwriting my class? How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a class attribute to a Symfony2 form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734821/how-to-set-a-class-attribute-to-a-symfony2-form-input)

Comment: There should be more to your builder than the line you gave us, form-control is not coming out of nowhere, what about adding the class to the builder ?

Comment: @DylanKas I have tried to add the class in the builder and it is the same

Comment: I would guess that the "form-control" class comes from your global form theme (which might be something that you have written yourself or just using some predefined one like bootstrap that makes that kind of additions). So the form theme would be the place to fix this (either fixing your own - or extending and fixing the predefined one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using a bootstrap form theme, check into the config file.

and if the case, you can add this line on the top of your twig file :

> {% form_theme form 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

Comment: Yes! The problem was that it doesn't have the default theme form. 
I solved with this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it will help you

```js
{{ form_start(form) }}
 {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'input-text input-text--white', 'placeholder': 'name'} }) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: It is the same with or without quotes. Notice that it is getting the placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't define two attributes on `form_wdiget`. The way around this is doing both in the FormBuilder or one in the FormBuilder.

You can define attributes on a form element like so:

```
$builder
    ->add('name', TextType::class, [
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'my-class',
        ],
    ]);
```

Note that for a CSS class, it must be in the array `attr`, not to be confused with a class as in your entity like on the `EntityType::class`.

Or

```
$builder
    ->add('name', TextType::class, [
        'placeholder' => 'My place holder',
    ]);
```

So you could achieve both like:

```
$builder
    ->add('name', TextType::class, [
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'my-class',
        ],
        'placeholder' => 'My place holder',
    ]);
```

You can read more about form field attributes [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#attr).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried also this options, but the result is the same.

Comment: Did you remove the 'attr' from form_widget when you tried my suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I did. At the beginning I also thought that it was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can read it from the official page:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#attr

Just add: {'attr': {'attribute name': 'value'}}

As shown below

```
{{ form_widget(form.propertyName, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'name'} }) }}
```